# Flutter 3: How can I check a certain widget is pushed in the stack or not?

Tags: flutter

This issue might look duplicate, but I couldn't find its duplicate in Stackoverflow.

I have notification widget which is embedded in main Widget, when notification arrives I want to pop a certain widget if available in the stack.

We can check if the current widget is visible by  `ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent;` but, in my case notification is not in current widget.

any solution please?

Update: even if I can list all the widgets pushed in the stack might help.

I tried `ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.name`, it always returns the first route name pushed.

this  `bool canPop = Navigator.of(context).canPop();` will give any popable widget not my target widget only.